# Not getting all values of a single column in a line or scatter chart diagram using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In a excel file named "chart.xlsx" i have these data as follows-

name  age  bloodgrp

ad  14  a+

as  42  o+

sd  21  o-

df  55  ab-

fg  44  a-

gh  87  b-

hj  26  b+

jk  24  ab+

kl  28  b-

i read these data using apache poi and i want to plot a line chart/ scatter chart in a excel file .

```
package tkl;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;


public class DemoTrendTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Chart.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    XSSFSheet s= wb.getSheet("a");
    Iterator <Row> rowIterator = s.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        //For each row, iterate through all the columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if(cell.getCellType()== Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
            }

        }

    }

    Drawing drawing = s.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor= drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 14, 20);
    Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);
    ScatterChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();
    ValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
    ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(s, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2));
    ChartDataSource<Number> ys2 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(s, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 1,1));

//actually should get =SERIES(a!$B$1,,a!$B$2:$B$10,1) but getting =SERIES(,a!$A$1:$J$1,a!$B$2:$B$11,1)

    data.addSerie(xs, ys2);
    chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D://1chart.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

i want to plot 14,42,21, 55,44,87,26,24,28 data in the chart. the problem i'm facing that only first  3 values are taking in the chart. i'm getting =SERIES(,a!$A$1:$J$1,a!$B$2:$B$11,1) but i want =SERIES(a!$B$1,,a!$B$2:$B$10,1). How can i get all the values in the chart? Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed 2 lines

```
ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(s, new CellRangeAddress(0, 9, 1, 1));
ChartDataSource<Number> ys2 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(s, new CellRangeAddress(1, 9, 1,1));
```

now i can see my output.

Answer (score 0):

You are only supplying 3 x axis values:

`ChartDataSource xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(s, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2));`

If you change that line to:

`ChartDataSource xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(s, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 0, 1));`

then you will see all of your data points.